# Spark-Kafka integration : python exception

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to read data from Apache Kafka topic in Spark on windows 10 machine. The program to read the Kafka topic is written in Python. But getting error during execution of line

```
KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, "spark-streaming-consumer", {topic: 
1})
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Work/kafka_wordcount.py", line 18, in <module>
    kvs = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, "spark-streaming-consumer", {topic: 1})
  File "D:\softwares\ApacheSpark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\streaming\kafka.py", line 70, in createStream
  File "D:\softwares\ApacheSpark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "D:\softwares\ApacheSpark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o27.createStream.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/Logging
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createStream(KafkaUtils.scala:81)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createStream(KafkaUtils.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtilsPythonHelper.createStream(KafkaUtils.scala:555)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.Logging
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 26 more
```

The version of Spark is 2.2.0.
The command executed to run the python script is:

> spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.2.0 D:\Work\kafka_wordcount.py localhost:2181 wordcounttopic

I went through almost all the threads and tried changing the spark-streaming-kafka library versions but in all cases got the same error.